# How to calculate mean sojourn time in each nonabsorbing state using R package MSTATE

Tags: r, survival-analysis, markov-chains

I am working on a survival analysis and cannot seem to figure out how do to this.

From the MSTATE tutorial the following is a block of code for as simple Cox-regression.  
 How does one calculate the mean sojourn time in each nonabsorbing state?

**Code:**

```
library(mstate)
data(ebmt3)
tmat <- trans.illdeath(names=c("Tx","PR","RelDeath"))
ebmt3$prtime <- ebmt3$prtime/365.25
ebmt3$rfstime <- ebmt3$rfstime/365.25
covs <- c("dissub", "age", "drmatch", "tcd", "prtime")
msbmt <- msprep(time = c(NA, "prtime", "rfstime"), status = c(NA, "prstat", "rfsstat"), data = ebmt3, trans = tmat, keep = covs)
expcovs <- expand.covs(msbmt, covs[2:3], append = FALSE)
msbmt <- expand.covs(msbmt, covs, append = TRUE, longnames = FALSE)
c1 <- coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, status) ~ dissub1.1 + dissub2.1 +
 age1.1 + age2.1 + drmatch.1 + tcd.1 + dissub1.2 + dissub2.2 +
 age1.2 + age2.2 + drmatch.2 + tcd.2 + dissub1.3 + dissub2.3 +
 age1.3 + age2.3 + drmatch.3 + tcd.3 + strata(trans), data = msbmt,
 method = "breslow")

newd <- data.frame(dissub = rep(0, 3), age = rep(0, 3), drmatch = rep(0,
 3), tcd = rep(0, 3), trans = 1:3)
 newd$dissub <- factor(newd$dissub, levels = 0:2, labels = levels(ebmt3$dissub))
 newd$age <- factor(newd$age, levels = 0:2, labels = levels(ebmt3$age))
 newd$drmatch <- factor(newd$drmatch, levels = 0:1, labels = levels(ebmt3$drmatch))
 newd$tcd <- factor(newd$tcd, levels = 0:1, labels = levels(ebmt3$tcd))
 attr(newd, "trans") <- tmat
 class(newd) <- c("msdata", "data.frame")
 newd <- expand.covs(newd, covs[1:4], longnames = FALSE)
 newd$strata = 1:3
 newd
 msf1 <- msfit(c1, newdata = newd, trans = tmat)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework? You should first describe the structure of the transition matrix. The transitions will be different for various covariate values. If you want transition probabilities (from which mean sojourn values are derived, since this is a Markov model) you need to specify which covariate values are desired. Read `?msfit`.

Comment: Homework - I wish!  Heck then I could go ask the Prof.  Nope, I am self taught so I am struggling with the fluctuating terminology.  I can see the transition probabilities but how do you calculate the sojourn?

Comment: Then that makes two of us. Once you have the transition matrix then I believe it is a fairly straightforward. So I say again, .... specify your covariates.

Comment: OK so now you can see that `tmat` is the transition matrix and I fitted `msf1`.  BTW, nothing about this is straightforward for me :)

Comment: Unfortunately that object's msf1$trans component is not a matrix of transition probabilities. It really only a labeling of state-to-state transitions. A transition probability matrix (which is the mathematical object  I have seen used in the past called a "transition matrix") would have row-sums all equal to 1. This package does have a plot method, so `plot(msf1)` may be informative. I'm thinking this data needs to be processed by either the msm or SemiMarkov package to get a standard transition (probability) matrix.

Comment: I'll add that my sometimes hazy memory was that the sojourn times were the eigenvalues (or perhaps their nagatives)  of the inverse of the transition matrix. I suspect this this would need to be a continuous time transition matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the ELOS function in mstate - it stands for the Expected Length of Stay in a state - to complete your example you would need to calculate the transition probabilities using probtrans and then you can calculate ELOS for every state.

```
pt <- probtrans(msf1,predt=0)
# ELOS until last observed time point
ELOS(pt)
```